# German language and grammar books in German for non-natives

Tags: grammar, reference-request

I have a book called **Bonniers Tyska Grammatik (Bonniers German Grammar)** and **Lust auf Deutsch** series, these books are not half bad but the authors are obsessed with comparing German and Swedish, and I feel like I'm wasting my time with them and **Lust auf Deutsch**s are from the 90s. I just finished *Anfängerkurs 1*, and the next course starts in 4 days, but they teach us grammar rather slow and even if I learn new words I find myself lost when trying to build sentences and they tell us we don't need to know this or that because it's just a beginner's course and I would like to try and build sentences because I seem to remember much better when I do that. Anyways, I would like to know if there are any books that teach German grammar with many examples? *Maybe books used to teach German to foreigners in Germany (maybe they teach German using the German language and not English in these books)*? I know grammatical gender is sort of tricky for non-natives, but that I do not worry about for the moment. Any help is appreciated!